# Permission Sets for Roles in ASP.NET Membership Provider using MVC 2.0 - Help

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

I am planning to write a Role Base Access Control Mechanism. What I thought is to have a set of permissions, which can be associated with each role. Normally Membership provider comes with normal roles and its details  not with Permission sets.   Roles with permission can be assigned to the new users. Permission Sets to Roles will give more flexibility compared to normal roles. Can any help me to do this ?

Thanks in Advance.

Best Regards,
Rajesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement your own authorization attribute, where instead of just checking which roles the user belongs to, you could check the permission sets that you have associated with the role(s) (or user).

I think [this article](http://schotime.net/blog/index.php/2009/02/17/custom-authorization-with-aspnet-mvc/) is a good starting point.